# Bootstrap and horizontal radio buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to display radio buttons horizontally using `Bootstrap-CSS` and `Flask-WTForms`. As far as I understand, I need to use the Bootstrap class `class_="radio-inline"` to accomplish that. I've tried it and all I get is this:

[image]

where radio buttons are, discouragingly, organized vertically.

**Flask WTForm code:**

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
import csv
import os
import buildHome as bh
from wtforms import TextField, RadioField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators, BooleanField

class ContactForm(Form):

    firstName = TextField("First name",  [validators.Required("Please enter your first name.")])
    lastName = TextField("Last name",  [validators.Required("Please enter your last name.")])
    #name = TextField("Name",  [validators.Required("Please enter your name.")])
    email = TextField("Email",  [validators.Required("Please enter your email address."), validators.Email("Please enter your email address.")])

    node_1 = BooleanField("Joan Johnson (Buckridge Inc)")
    direction_1 = RadioField('', choices=[('Choice1','Choice1'),('Choice2','Choice2'),('Choice3','Choice3')])
    freq_1 = RadioField('', choices=[(1,'Daily'),(7,'Weekly'),(30,'Monthly'),(183,'Yearly'),(365,'More')])

    submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

**Html template for Flask to create the html code**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method=post>

{{ form.hidden_tag() }}

<h3>Part I</h3>

<div class="well span6">
<div>
    {{ form.firstName.label }} {{ form.firstName }}
</div>

<div>
    {{ form.lastName.label }} {{ form.lastName }}
</div>

<div>
    {{ form.email.label }} {{ form.email }} 
</div> 
</div>

<h3>Part II</h3>

<div <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"> 

<div class="well span6">
    {{ form.node_1 (class_="checkbox style-2 pull-left") }} {{ form.node_1.label(class_="col-sm-3 control-label") }}
    {{ form.direction_1.label }} {{ form.direction_1 (class_="radio-inline") }}
    {{ form.freq_1.label }} {{ form.freq_1 (class_="radio-inline") }} 
</div>

{{ form.submit }}{% endblock %}
```

**Html script, produced by the Flask WTForm script above**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>TITLE</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
            </head>
            <body>

            <header>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="logo">LOGO</h1>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>

                <div class="container">

        <form action="/" method=post>
        <div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1454454094##65db3f398f17785503e4bf13dfe76ad4879eb792"></div>
        <h3>
        Part I</h3>
        <div class="well span6">
        <div>
        <label for="firstName">First name</label> <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for="lastName">Last name</label> <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <div>
         <label for="email">Email</label> <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value=""> 
        </div>

        </div>

        <h3>Part II</h3>
        <div <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"> 

        <div class="well span6">
        <input class="checkbox style-2 pull-left" id="node_1" name="node_1" type="checkbox" value="y"> <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="node_1">Joan Johnson (Buckridge Inc)</label>
        <label for="direction_1"></label> <ul class="radio-inline" id="direction_1"><li><input id="direction_1-0" name="direction_1" type="radio" value="Choice1"> <label for="direction_1-0">Choice1</label></li><li><input id="direction_1-1" name="direction_1" type="radio" value="Choice2"> <label for="direction_1-1">Choice2</label></li><li><input id="direction_1-2" name="direction_1" type="radio" value="Choice3"> <label for="direction_1-2">Choice3</label></li></ul>
        <label for="freq_1"></label> <ul class="radio-inline" id="freq_1"><li><input id="freq_1-0" name="freq_1" type="radio" value="1"> <label for="freq_1-0">Daily</label></li><li><input id="freq_1-1" name="freq_1" type="radio" value="7"> <label for="freq_1-1">Weekly</label></li><li><input id="freq_1-2" name="freq_1" type="radio" value="30"> <label for="freq_1-2">Monthly</label></li><li><input id="freq_1-3" name="freq_1" type="radio" value="183"> <label for="freq_1-3">Yearly</label></li><li><input id="freq_1-4" name="freq_1" type="radio" value="365"> <label for="freq_1-4">More</label></li></ul> 
        </div>
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">



                </div>

            </body>
        </html>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm probably missing something rather obvious, but can't get my finger on it. Also, it's my first time using Bootstrap or any CSS styling for that matter. So that might be it

In short, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a <form> tag inside of your first <div>.  You don't have a closing </form> tag.

Comment: oh ok, I'll try fix this...

Comment: @jasonwarford, I edited my question with the full html as rendered by flask WTForms. It should make the question clearer... Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Forms should contain the "form-group" class. This can prevent other classes from working. Also, you have one form nested to the other, I have never seen such thing. Try using divs instead of nesting forms. And for last, remove the list elements and try using this:
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
</label>
This is in the bootstrap documentation.

Comment: Thanks @PauloPedroso ! As far as your last point, I realize some of my issue may come from the fact that I generate html with Flask WTForms, I edited my question, does it make more sense? I'm trying to fix your two first points. Thanks so much for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: It seems you have no control of what's being generated in the radio buttons area. I have had a lot of trouble learning bootstrap and it is very sensitive to nesting classes in the wrong tags.

Comment: Ok... I don't particularly need to use bootstrap, but rather to have my radio buttons horizontal. Do you think another approach would be easier?

Comment: I added precisions to the questions, in case it helps... Cheers!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found a solution!

All I needed to do was to iterate through my radio buttons field while building the html template, like so:

```
{% for subfield in form.freq_1 %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ subfield }}</td>
    <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks. But the <tr> and <td> tags are not required.
Also for boostrap styling I had to put the class else it is just default HTML styling

{% for subfield in form.item %}
        {{ subfield(class="form-check-input") }}
        {{ subfield.label(class="form-check-label me-2") }}
{% endfor %}